# Does PowerShell automatically reduce dimensions in size 1 in multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: powershell

I'm a novice in PowerShell. I've worked on my personal Powershell module
[PSComputerManagementZp](https://github.com/Zhaopudark/PSComputerManagementZp) for a while.

Recently, I wanted to give a class method a parameter in the type of array, such as `string[]`, and encountered confusion about parentheses: there seems no difference within the following syntax (nesting does not work):

```
class foo{
    foo(){
    }
    [void] func($bar){
        Write-Host "Bar:$($bar), Count:$($bar.Count)"
    }
}
$_foo = [foo]::new()
$array = 'a;b;c' -split ';'
$_foo.func($array) 

$_foo.func('a;b;c' -split ';')          # Bar:a b c, Count:3
$_foo.func(@('a;b;c' -split ';'))       # Bar:a b c, Count:3
$_foo.func(@(@('a;b;c' -split ';')))    # Bar:a b c, Count:3
$_foo.func(@(@(@('a;b;c' -split ';')))) # Bar:a b c, Count:3

$_foo.func(@(@(@(1),@(2),@(3)))) # Bar:System.Object[] System.Object[] System.Object[], Count:3
$_foo.func(@(@(1),@(2),@(3))) # Bar:System.Object[] System.Object[] System.Object[], Count:3
$_foo.func(@(1,2,3)) # Bar:a b c, Count:3
```

It seems any redundant dimension will be ignored. Then, I did the following tests:

```
@(1,2,3)
# 1
# 2
# 3
@(1,2,3) -eq 1
# 1
@(@(1),@(2),@(3)) # dims=3x1
# 1
# 2
# 3
@(@(1),@(2),@(3)) -eq 1
# Shows Nothing 
@(@(1),@(2),@(3)) -eq @(1)
# Shows Nothing
```

So I think there may be some special mechanism for `nesting` arrays. Even though it looks like an `auto dimension reducing on size 1` but does not influence the inner levels' dimensions. Or, it seems like a pre-processing mechanism before establishing a multi-dimensional array, not a post-processing mechanism to reduce redundant dimensions.

My problem is:

- Why the above phenomenon and what the mechanism is?
- Can define a `1*1*1*3` dims array as (not work but I hope it may be):

```
$nested_array = @(@(@(@(1,2,3)))) 
$nested_array[0][0][0][1] -eq 2 # true
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks. You are right. Actually, my problem comes from `class` and `methods` and now I have edited it to be more precise.